# VBScript Loop in a Loop

Tags: loops, vbscript

I have a quick question regarding Loops in Loops using Do Until. Will the first loop run the second loop if the criteria for the second one was fulfilled?

For Example:

```
Dim X
Dim Y
X = 0
Y = 0
' Loop 1
Do Until X = 20
   ' Loop 2
   Do Until Y = 5
   Y = Y + 1
   Loop
X = X + 1
Loop
```

So, loop 1 should loop 20 times and every time it loops it should run the second loop that loops 5 * 20 times. It doesn't seem to work. The second loop only seem to run 1 time and be ignored the rest of the time.

[How to loop a loop in VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560557/how-to-loop-a-loop-in-vbscript) Didn't help me to much.

Comment: You're missing the `Y = 0` to reset the inner loop on each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Apparently [How to loop a loop in VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560557/how-to-loop-a-loop-in-vbscript) didn't help you much? I can only assume you didn't read it or follow it properly, that example is pretty comprehensive. Note the final comment on that answer *"Without `z = 0` the second loop won't be entered after the first turn."* which is exactly the issue here except your variable is `y = 0` not `z = 0` but same applies.

Comment: Who close votes - *"unclear what you're asking"*? Really??, seems pretty clear to me! It is however a duplicate plain and simple.

Comment: @Lankymart probably someone in the close-vote review queue that's not very well versed in vbscript. I've seen it happen plenty of times before, not that it makes it right...

Comment: You can Search `For Loop` Or `Do While Loop` in the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the first time your inner loop runs, it exits when `Y = 5` - as you do not change the value of `Y` again it will not run the next time because the condition has already been met.

Try this instead:

```
Dim X
Dim Y
X = 0
Y = 0
' Loop 1
Do Until X = 20
   ' Loop 2
   Do Until Y = 5
   Y = Y + 1
   Loop
   Y = 0 '// reset value of Y so that inner loop will run next time around
X = X + 1
Loop
```

or use a `For...To...` loop instead:

```
Dim X,Y

For X = 1 To 20
'// Do something...
    For Y = 1 To 5
    '// Do something 5 times
    Next
Next
```

---

This is because of the `Y` variables **scope** as you declared and assigned it's initial value *outside* of the loops.

You can read more about variable scope in VBScript in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2)

Comment: Good explanation. It's just personal preference but I always initialise / reset variables before the loop rather then after.

Answer (score 0):

`Y` reaches `5` the *first time* the inner loop runs, so the next time round it already meets the `until y = 5` condition so the loop never runs again.

Reset it before the loop or when the loop completes.

```
Y = 0
Do Until Y = 5
```